# OS fingerprinting via scapy fails

Tags: python, tcp, fingerprint, scapy

I am playing around with scapy and I am trying to fingerprint OS. So I did the following:

```
>>> load_module("p0f")  
>>> pkts = sniff(iface="wlan0",count=1,filter="tcp")
>>> pkts
<Sniffed: TCP:1 UDP:0 ICMP:0 Other:0>
```

But on calling `p0f()` I got an error:

```
>>> pkts[0]
<Ether  dst=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX src=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX type=0x800 |<IP  version=4L ihl=5L tos=0x0 len=60 id=54922 flags=DF frag=0L ttl=64 proto=tcp chksum=0xd51a src=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX dst=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX options=[] |<TCP  sport=58370 dport=www seq=2898076075 ack=0 dataofs=10L reserved=0L flags=S window=14600 chksum=0xd450 urgptr=0 options=[('MSS', 1460), ('SAckOK', ''), ('Timestamp', (28571425, 0)), ('NOP', None), ('WScale', 7)] |>>>
>>> p0f(pkts[0])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/modules/p0f.py", line 278, in p0f
    d = p0f_correl(sig,b)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/modules/p0f.py", line 238, in p0f_correl
    d += (y[1] >= x[1] and y[1] - x[1] < 32)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

I am not sure what the problem is. Any ideas?

- Scapy is version 2.2.0
- p0f.fp database is installed (p0f 3.0b)

**[update]**
some additional information:

- pylibpcap-0.6.4
- libpcap 1.4.0-1
- Linux 3.9.8-1-ARCH x86_64

using the database of p0f-2.0.8 produces:

```
>>> load_module("p0f")
>>> pkts = sniff(iface="wlan0", filter="tcp", count=1)
>>> pkts[0]
<Ether  dst=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX src=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX type=0x800 |<IP  version=4L ihl=5L tos=0x0 len=60 id=20361 flags=DF frag=0L ttl=64 proto=tcp chksum=0xf723 src=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX dst=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX options=[] |<TCP  sport=59013 dport=www seq=4006166884 ack=0 dataofs=10L reserved=0L flags=S window=14600 chksum=0xf32f urgptr=0 options=[('MSS', 1460), ('SAckOK', ''), ('Timestamp', (29888237, 0)), ('NOP', None), ('WScale', 7)] |>>>
>>> p0f(pkts[0])
[]
```

Comment: What platform (and version) are you on? Which `libpcap`, `pylibpcap`, etc. Also, have you tried looking in the bug database? Because this sure looks like a bug in scapy, not in your code.

Comment: I updated my question. The database itself does not seem to be buggy though.

Comment: Can you post the output for str(pkts[0])? I want to ensure I don't get p0f output for the packets you aren't getting it for.

Comment: To my knowledge, Scapy right now only supports p0f 2.0. The major increment to p0f 3.0 isn't backwards compatible.

Comment: I gave p0f 2.0.4 a try and print(repr(p0f(pkts[0]))) returns [], too.

Comment: Still having this issue?

Comment: @RyPeck It did not work for a while, so I gave up a while ago. I have no idea, what the current status is.